# How to monitor how much data transfers between Exchange servers in DAG?

Tags: exchange-2010, network-monitoring, disaster-recovery

I recently installed a second Exchange Server (standard, 2010) to our organization as part of a Disaster Recovery solution.  The two servers will soon be part of a DAG.  Before placing the server at our remote location I was curious as to the amount of data that is transferred back and forth between the two servers.

Is there a way to monitor or get a daily report of how much data is transferred per second and/or per day between the two?  I would like to have an average metric so as to know if our current connection will be saturated or not.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try use the Outlook Profile Analyzer to see some outlook statistics there.
If not using circular logging you could look and see how many logs that are generated per day.
Then I think you could use perfmon to see the amount of traffic utilized on the loggshipping NIC (if you have a separated replication NIC)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the statistics gathering that WireShark can do to measure network traffic, this will be easier if you have separate replication network adapters.  Have a read of the PDF [Using Wireshark to Create Network-Usage Baselines](http://wiki.wireshark.org/KnownBugs/OutOfMemory?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=Using+Wireshark+to+Create+Network-Usage+Baselines.pdf) and you should be able to produce some decent metrics.